# Put page numbers at the bottom center with \pagestyle{headings}

Tags: header-footer, numbering, fancyhdr

I use the `\pagestyle{headings}` to show headers in my article in Latex. But the pages numbers appear at the top right corner. How can I make it appear at the bottom center of the page ? I don't want to use the `fancyhdr` package since it overlays headers with some table that I display in landscape format. Here is a code sample

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
Test 
\pagestyle{headings}
\section{Chapter 1}
Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: if you like to have page numbers centered at bottom of pages, don't use `\pagestyle{headings}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want headers and a centered page number, you need to define a couple of things yourself. The [`fancyhdr`-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) is quite useful.

In this example, I'll assume there won't be any double-sided printing involved, so the code is pretty straightforward:

- *rhead* (right head)
- *lhead* (left head)
- *cfoot* (center foot)

The manual explains it well, I think:

> There are 12 places defined: Left, Center and Right Headers and Footers, and both can be on Even or Odd pages. Each place therefore has 3 coordinates which are the inital letters of the above description: (1) E or O, (2) L, C or R, (3) H or F.

For a one-sided document it would look like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Right side head}
\lhead{Left side head}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{introduction}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: Single-sided centered page number]